# Horizontal List Exceeding Right Margin

Tags: css, html-lists

I've created a simple horizontal list for links at the footer of my web pages. The problem is that the list exceeds the right margin of div id="footer-links" before it wraps around to the next line. This happens when viewed in my iPad held in Portrait mode resolution 768.

This problem is driving me absolutely crazy!! I greatly appreciate any help on this.

I tried to post a picture from my iPad but it won't let me since I'm new. Here is the code:

The HTML is simple:

```
<div id="links-wrapper">
<div id="footer-links">
<p>Info</p>
<ul>
 <li class="first"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Link 7</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#links-wrapper {
width:auto;
}

#footer-links {
margin:0 4.545455%;
font-size:.85em;
line-height:175%;
}

#footer-links ul {
margin: 0px 0 30px;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#footer-links li {
display:inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 .4em 0 .6em;
border-left: 1px solid;
}

#footer-links .first {
padding-left: 0;
border: 0;
}

#footer-links p {
font-weight:700;
margin-bottom:1px;
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: And what are hopig for exactly? Do you want them to not wrap? If so, you have to options. 1. lower the font size and padding between them. 2. If you want to keep font size (responsive approach) then you have to design these links to take a display block and LIs to width 100% so they stack over each other instead.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting the links to wrap but not exceed the right margin. I am trying to keep everything lined up for a responsive design. I can manipulate the font size and make it wrap at the right place to where it doesn't exceed the right-margin on my iPad. But I can't test this on every device at every resolution. So I would like to know what is causing it. There is a reason for it, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clay, You can do this by applying a display:block to the LIs inside a media query for the width you want them to respond to. For example:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
   #footer-links li {
      display:block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 .4em 0 .6em;
      border-left: 1px solid;
   }  
}
```

See [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYLagY)

But with that in mind, if you are building a responsive design, you should look into a responsive design framework. They have all of this coded out for you to use. The best and most efficient is Bootstrap3. Look into it and specially into nav-pills.

Good luck

**EDIT**

In response to your comment below. I understad. I often go through the same deal. In that case you can modify your code and use DIVs instead of LIs. Then use the proper bootstrap classes and cascading to adjust according to screen size to all inline, then two columns of links and then on sigle column on smartphones .

See this other [**DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPoXeN) for a different alternative

*hint, With a little creativity, you may be able to keep your LI's and stack them up like my first example but add a logo or something else next to it as a filler ;)

Comment: Hi LOTUSMS, thank you for taking the time to look at this I really appreciate it. Your solution is where I was headed with smaller displays as in 320px mobile displays. However between desktop and mobile I didn't want the list to go block just yet. I thought it looked too narrow for anything larger than say 568 mobile in landscape. However I may be forced to go this route. I will look at your other suggestion, but even if I find another way to do this it will still bother me until I figure out what is making the list behave that way. :) Just wish I had the rep score to post my screenshot pic.

Comment: Another way to do it is to getout of using LIs and use DIVs. Then if you can spread them all even accross form 768px to 1200px, in two columns from 480px to 767px, and a whole stack of one column form 380 to 479px;

Comment: All good thoughts and very cool example above. I am going to stick with your original stacking solution for now just so I can keep moving forward. Adding a filler is also a good idea. In the meantime I'll do some research on bootstrap. Cheers.